# Using a regular expression to validate a time entry field in a PDF form

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have created the following JavaScript function in my PDF form:

```
var rgTime = /^[^0-9]{1,2}[^:][^0-9]{2}$/;
function testTimeEntry(t) {
if (rgTime.test(t)){
app.alert("Opps!  Time entry is invalid.  Only numbers and the colon(:) are allowed.");
event.value = "";
}
}
```

Then I use `testTimeEntry(event.value);` in the validation portion of my time field.  However, it only works if I complete the field with 5 letters.  I am basically trying to catch the accidental use of the semi-colon (or anything other than the colon) and alpha characters in this field.

I am not using the time format for the field on purpose, but I still need to make sure the inputted format is 12 hr (hh:mm).  Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you can use the `time` input type which validates the time https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression string `rgTime = /^[^0-9]{1,2}[^:][^0-9]{2}$/` will only match with a string that is entirely invalid input. If the user inputs a valid 'hh' value then this regular expression will not match. As an example the string `"11:1s"` would not be matched by your regular expression.

Perhaps it would be easier to look for a valid input and alert them if it wasn't valid

```
var rgTime = /^[0-9]{1,2}[:][0-9]{2}$/;
function testTimeEntry(t) {
if (!rgTime.test(t)){
app.alert("Opps!  Time entry is invalid.  Only numbers and the colon(:) are allowed.");
event.value = "";
}
}
```

Comment: This is perfect.  I added a statement to avoid an empty entry field as well and it works.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this `/[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/`

Comment: This is the better answer.